# Encrypt URI string Codeigniter using URI or Router

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I have url : `http://localhost/auth/123?org=12&use_id=12`
i need to encrypt after "?" auto using core/router or core/URI.
any idea how can i do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use SSL (`https') and don't worry about it. Or don't pass sensitive data in the URL use session data instead. What you need to know about URL Parameter Encryption can be found [on this page](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)

Comment: i agreed but is there any way i can replace query_string by encrypted data. as i mentioned in question. by using Router file or URI file. i dig everywhere but didn't find in both files.

Comment: The router is probably where you would be decrypting the query string. The encryption will have to happen before a redirect, or in the case of links on a page, before the page is generated.

Comment: It might also be possible to use the output class to encrypt link (`href=`) query strings. It would involve a search/encode/replace of the entire output buffer. The URI arguments to `redirect()` would need to be encoded before that page is displayed as I said earlier.

Comment: You gotta at least try something before asking

Comment: I have written encryption and decryption code but the thing is , i dont want to use that function on href . asking is there any way to hack Router or URI file  where i can encrypt **query_string** before it pass to controller.. in a simple manner when url requested from config/router.php query_string goes encrypt then i will decrypt over controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [You're trying to solve the wrong problem](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).

Encrypting URI parameters is almost never the solution you want.

You want to use HTTPS (HTTP over TLS) to encrypt your parameters to protect them in transit.

If you want to obfuscate them from your users, encryption isn't the tool you want here.

#### Don't Do This:

[image: encrypt URL parameters]

#### Do This Instead:

[image: use a lookup instead]

If you re-think how you architect your software, and [develop a threat model](https://adamcaudill.com/2016/07/20/threat-modeling-for-applications/), you'll arrive at a better solution than what you were asking for.